# How to combine two jQuery results

Tags: jquery

How do you combine two jQuery search results? eg:

```
var $allFoos = $('.foo'),
    $allBars = $('.bar')
    $allFoosAndBars = $allFoos + $allBars;
```

Obviously, I just made up that last line, but I hope it makes it sorta clear what I mean. To be clear, the example is greatly simplified, and it could be any arbitrary sets i'm talking about, so `$('.foo, .bar')` is *not* what I'm after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging jQuery objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881716/merging-jquery-objects)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You can use [add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/);

```
var $foos = $('.foo');

var $foosAndBars = $foos.add('.bar');
```

or

```
var $allFoosAndBars = $allFoos.add($allBars);
```

Comment: Note that in the line "$all.add('.bar');", variable $all is not changed and thus, does not hold all elements. You would need to assign the return value again like "$all = $all.add('.bar');".

Comment: If you want to make it more apparent that you are combining the two and not adding one set to the other (as the name implies) you can to this: `var $allFoosAndBars = $().add($allFoos).add($allBars);`

Comment: The method should have been called "and" instead of "add" -- would be more intuitive.

Comment: @Faust For those familiar with set operations, AND and UNION are very different.

Comment: Why is $.merge() not mentioned here?

Comment: If you want to combine more than two result sets:
`function combine() {
        var i;
        var combined = $();
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            combined = combined.add(arguments[i]);
        }
        return combined;
    }`

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to use [jQuery.merge()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/) *(jQuery > 1.0)*

> Description: Merge the contents of two arrays together into the first
> array.

So you could simply use it to merge both result :

```
var $allFoos = $('.foo');
var $allBars = $('.bar');

var $allFoosAndBars = $.merge($allFoos, $allBars);
```

Comment: Be aware that `$.merge` is destructive, so `$allBars` would be merged into `$allFoos` as well as returned in `$allFoosAndBars`... which is probably not what you want