# Merging jQuery objects

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to merge several jQuery DOM objects into one array and call jQuery methods on all of them?

F.ex:

```
<button>one</button>
<h3>two</h3>

<script>

var btn = $('button');
var h3 = $('h3');

$([btn,h3]).hide();

</script>
```

This doesn't work. I know I can use the 'button,h3' selector here but in some cases I already have several jQuery DOM elements and I need to merge them so I can call jQuery prototypes on all of them.

something like:

```
$.merge([btn,h3]).hide();
```

would work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Solved it. You can do it like this:

```
$.fn.add.call(btn,h3);
```

I'm going to accept the `add()` suggestion as for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @David, why the bizarre use of `call`? `btn.add(h3)` works...

Comment: Because I do not know the first object, so I can't chain. Apply() would be even better, so I can send an array using $.fn.add.apply(arr.shift(),arr);

Comment: is there a way to add more than 2 objects ?

Comment: If you don't know the first object, you can avoid using `call` by chaining off an empty jQuery object: `$().add(btn).add(h3)`. IMO, this is a much better way to use `$.add`.

Comment: `$.fn.add.call()` will fail if its first argument is not a jQuery object.

Comment: is this basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results

Comment: Weird, but nice way to use add in my opinion, as far as you don't want to chain .add()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine two jQuery results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results)

Answer (score 33):

[`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) does exactly what you're after.

```
h3.add(btn).hide();
```

If you wanted to make it a little more convenient for yourself, with a "merge" function like in your question, this could be added easily:

```
$.merge = function(objs) {
    var ret = objs.shift();
    while (objs.length) {
        ret = ret.add(objs.shift());
    }
    return ret;
};

$.merge([h3, btn]).hide()
```

Comment: JQuery now has a merge function so something other than $.merge should be used.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `jQuery.Add` method causes a new `jQuery` object to be produced instead of modifying the original object on which the method is called. Isn't it `ret = ret.Add(objs.shift());`?

Answer (score 8):

`$.map` can flatten arrays:

```
function merge(array_of_jquery_objects) {
    return $($.map(array_of_jquery_objects, function(el) {
        return el.get();
    }));
}
```

Comment: Useful when you're stuck with an old jQuery version (< 1.3.2).

Answer (score 5):

```
$(btn).add(h3).hide();
```

Not sure if it works though, [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/add/) for add doesn't mention haivng the jQuery object as a parameter but only a list of elements, so if that doesn't work this should:

```
$(btn).add(h3.get()).hide();
```

Comment: Not sure which version was active in 2009, but 1.3.2 added the `add(selector : jQuery)` overload.

Answer (score 3):

#### Get some jQuery objects:

```
var x = $('script'),
    y = $('b'),
    z = $('body');
```

#### Create a new jQuery object, containing all the other objects:

```
$( $.map([x,y,z], a => [...a]) )
```

## Demo: (open your browser's console)

```js
var x = $('script'),
    y = $('b'),
    z = $('body');

// step 1
// put all the jQuery objects in an Array to prepare for step 2
var step1 = [x,y,z];
console.log(step1)

// using jQuery.map and a callback, extract  the actual selector from the iterable 
// array item and return it, so the result would be a simple array of DOM nodes
// http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.map
var step2 = $.map(step1, a => [...$.makeArray(a)])
console.log(step2);

// convert the javascript Array into jQuery Object (which contains all the nodes)
var step3 = $( step2 )
console.log(step3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b></b>
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation about your solutions, please?

Answer (score 2):

Use this one.

```js
<script>

var btn = $('button')[0];
var h3 = $('h3')[0];

$([btn,h3]).hide();

</script>
```

Comment: This will only merge the very first element in each set, therefor it is far from an optimal answer. only good in very specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

To take the use of `add` a little farther, you could use `reduce` with it for another approach:

```
var $mySelector1 = $('.selector1');
var $mySelector2 = $('.selector2');
var $mySelector3 = $('.selector3');
var selectorArray = [$mySelector1,$mySelector2,$mySelector3];
var $combinedSelector = selectorArray.reduce(function(total, current){
    return $(total).add(current)
});
```