# jQuery, how to use multiple cached elements

Tags: jquery, performance, css-selectors, pagespeed

For my project I'm using cached selectors to speed up, and see improvements:
(to reduce searches inside the document)

```
var sel1 = $('#selector1');
var sel2 = $('#selector2');
```

how can I use cached selectors in this situation? for ex:

```
$('#selector1, #selector2').fadeTo(300, 1, 'linear');
```

It's just to polish up my code

Ty :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1881716/901048 for a possible approach.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `.add()` to "Add elements to the set of matched elements":

```
sel1.add(sel2).fadeTo(300, 1, 'linear');
```

Docs for `.add()`: http://api.jquery.com/add

`.add()` can take in:

- a selector
- DOM elements
- jQuery objects
- and selectors with context (`$('<selector>', <context>)`)

You can also pass an array of DOM elements to jQuery:

```
var one = $('#one')[0],
    two = $('#two')[0];

$([one, two]).fadeTo(300, 1, 'linear');
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3xJzE/

**UPDATE**

I created a jsperf of the three different methods that are currently answers: http://jsperf.com/jquery-fadeto-once-vs-twice (it seems like using an array selector is the fastest: `$([one, two]).fadeTo...`)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method for that;

```
sel1.add(sel2).fadeTo(300, 1, 'linear');
```

It'll be good if you add `$` prefix when naming your variables. This way you can distinguish them from standart javascript objects. So this is better:

```
var $sel1 = $('#selector1');
var $sel2 = $('#selector2');

$sel1.add($sel2).fadeTo(300, 1, 'linear');
```

Answer (score 7):

jQuery's [add](http://api.jquery.com/add)

```
sel1.add(sel2).fadeTo(300, 1, 'linear');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the selectors stored just apply the fadeTo to each one individually. JQuery will just have to parse the selector anyway...

```
sel1.fadeTo(300, 1, 'linear');
sel2.fadeTo(300, 1, 'linear');
```

Comment: @user690214: I cant image one fadeTo call on multiple elements is going to be any better. It still have to do the fade twice - once for each element - somewhere along the line

Comment: @user690214 Here is a jsperf to show the performance difference between using one `fadeTo` and using two of them. Also tested is using an array of DOM elements as the selector: http://jsperf.com/jquery-fadeto-once-vs-twice (seems like the array selector is the fastest: `$([sel1[0], sel2[0]]).fadeTo...`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sel1.add(sel2).fadeTo(300, 1, 'linear');
```