# combine jQuery Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881716/merging-jquery-objects)

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nZRLD/)

```
a = $('div:eq(0)');
b = $('div:eq(1)');
c = $('div:eq(2)');
d = $('div:eq(3)');
e = $('div:eq(4)');
f = $('div:eq(5)');

console.log($([a,b,c,d,e,f]).find('a'))
```

​

What I'm trying to do is add multiple jQuery objects to a single set.

I know I can add them one at a time by using `.add()` but I'm looking for a way to turn an array of jQuery  objects into a single jQuery set.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: jQuery uses the syntax you used for arrays of DOM elements already.

It's probably possible to make a plugin that would allow that syntax, but that would be confusing.

Best to either use .add() or make a plug-in that uses .add() to hide the syntax. It should be hard to make a $.fromArray() plugin.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/cGMd9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible in plain jQuery, as the syntax is already used for DOM elements.

But a simple plugin will do the job just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/gMDjZ/

```
a = $('div:eq(0)');
b = $('div:eq(1)');
c = $('div:eq(2)');
d = $('div:eq(3)');
e = $('div:eq(4)');
f = $('div:eq(5)');

jQuery.fromArray = function(a) {
    var c = jQuery();
    for(x in a) {
        c = c.add(a[x]);            
    }       
    return c;
}

console.log($.fromArray([a,b,c,d,e,f]).find('a'))
```

​

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `:` in your code. Write it as -

```
a = $('div:eq(0)');
```

Use `jQuery.merge()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/

or `jQuery.map()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/