# jquery selector, chaining

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881716/merging-jquery-objects)

** The goal is performance.  The duplicate question addresses the function, but I don't believe adds performance value and doesn't address that aspect. **

I want to chain several jQuery elements, for the sake of performance, but for optimization sake they're already cached in variables.

so if I have

```
$elem1 = $('div#elem1');
$elem2 = $('div#elem2');
$elem3 = $('div#elem3');
```

This doesn't work so well:

```
$elem1,$elem2,$elem3.hide();
```

Is there any way to do that, chaining with already cached elements?

Thanks!

[Edits]
Ok, I really need to clarify.  My goal for chaining is performance, with the bonus of concise yet clear code.
$('div#elem1, div#elem2, div#elem3').hide();

defeats the point as it's no longer using the cached vars, but accessing the dom again.  Accessing the dom is expensive, so i'm pretty sure it's slower than the 3 lines. 

.add() and  .merge(), I'm assuming are more expensive than seperating the operation on three lines.  For performance sake, until I have time to jPerf, I'll assume 3 different lines rather than extra operations has the best performance.

Thanks for the collaboration, brainstorming, and thoughts, I do appreciate it. I wasn't aware of the possibilities and wouldn't have known what to test on jPerf otherwise.

Comment: How would you chain these if they were 'uncached' elements?

Comment: If they were uncached it would be `$('div#elem1', 'div#elem2', 'div#elem3').hide()`

Comment: I think it would need to be this instead `$('div#elem1, div#elem2, div#elem3').hide()` passing multiple strings to jQuery doesn't work at least with my version...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much cleaner it is, but you can use jQuery's `each()` to iterate over an array of them. It's not exactly chaining, but the end result should be the same:

```
$.each([$elem1,$elem2,$elem3], function() {this.hide()})
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is putting all of them together with [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add)

```
$elem1.add($elem2).add($elem3).hide();
```

Comment: +1 - deleted my answer - i'd write it like this however `var $collection = $().add($elem1).add($elem2).add($elem3).hide();` rather than working with / modifiying an existing collection already.

Comment: @pebbl $elem1 will not be modified, add returns a new jQuery object.

Comment: Ah... very good point. foolish me. I shall be quiet now.

Answer (score 0):

No my friend, this will never work.
Try to do this

> $('div#elem1, div#elem2, div#elem3').hide();

or

> $elem1.hide(); $elem2.hide(); $elem3.hide()

Comment: or the add() function as talked before..

Comment: This completely defeats the point.  My goal is chaining for optimization.  The latter is not chaining - it's just compressing it into a single line.  The former, uses unchached vars, and selects the from the dom again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = [];
elements.push($elem1);
elements.push($elem2);
elements.push($elem3);

$(elements).each(function(i){
    elements[i].hide();
});
```