# jQuery combine multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I was experimenting with `jQuery` and came across a question. Can I use an `actual selector` with existing `element` as a combined selector for jQuery?

So, suppose I've created a `DIV` element on-the-fly:

```
var $div = $('<div>')
               .css('position', 'absolute')
               .hide();    // Just to be short

$('body').append($div);
```

And I want to show it when user hovers over `P` elements / paragraphs (at the cursor position):

```
$('p').hover(function(e) {

    // Change the position of $div with regards of cursor position

    $div.show();
}, function(e) {
    $div.hide();
});
```

**BUT** also I want to apply this `hover` handlers to `$div` itself. So instead of duplicating my code, I want to do something like this:

```
$('p', $div).hover(...)
```

which will select `$div` element along with all `P` elements.

I know I can write functions separately and pass the names as arguments to `hover` function.

Is there any solution to this kind of situation in jQuery? or is there a more accurate solution?

Comment: have a look at .add() http://api.jquery.com/add/ -- something like $("p").add($div) should do the trick

Comment: Just FYI `$('p', $div)` will select `p` elements inside the `$div`. It is the same as `$div.find('p');`. It is not aggregating the two selectors.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, I know that ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the jQuery [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$('p').add($div).hover(function(e) { ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't hear about that before.

Comment: add() is right when you have to combine only two elements, but what when you want to combine a lot? `$('p').add($div).add($div).add($div).add($div).add($div).add($div) ...` looks very dirty.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple elements to combine you don't wan to do

```
$('p').add($div1).add($div2).add($div3).add($div4).add($div5).add($div6) ...
```

Instead you want to convert a JavaScript array into a jQuery object

```
$( $.map([x,y,z], a => [...$.makeArray(a)]) )
```

Source: [Merging jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881716/merging-jquery-objects#answer-40223294)

Comment: You don't have to do `$('p').add($div1).add($div2)...`. It also accepts an array of elements (and html, and selection): http://api.jquery.com/add/#add-elements

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan You're right but there is still a difference, see https://i.imgur.com/YS7pFLK.png

Comment: Also the method I show will flatten the elements is they contains sub-elements.