# How to merge more than 2 DOM objects using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Is it possible to merge 3 or more DOM objects in jQuery? I found this solution here in stackoverflow, but it is only for merging 2 objects: [Merging jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881716/merging-jquery-objects)

**Example:**

```
var input1 = $('.input-1'),
    input2 = $('#parent-div input'),
    input3 = $('.input-3'),
    input4 = $('.input-4'),
    input5 = $('.input-5')

    merge([input1, input2, input3, input4]).val('My custom input text');
```

In my case I have several inputs but i only want to merge few of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we use `$.add()` only in following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input1 = $('.input-1');
   var input2 = $('#parent-div input');
   var input3 = $('.input-3');
   var input4 = $('.input-4');
   var input5 = $('.input-5');
  
  var collection = $( input1 );
  // Capture the new collection
  collection = collection.add( input2).add(input3).add(input4);
  collection.val('My custom input text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-1" value="defualt text" >
<div id="parent-div">
  <input type="text" class="input-2" value="defualt text" >
  <input type="text" class="input-3" value="defualt text" >
</div>  
<input type="text" class="input-3" value="defualt text" >
<input type="text" class="input-4" value="defualt text" >
<input type="text" class="input-5" value="defualt text" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper function that just iterates over the array of jQuery objects:

```
function merge(jqs) {
  var obj = $();
  jqs.forEach(function (jq) {
    obj.add(jq);
  });
  return obj;
}
```

You might also try something like this:

```
function merge(jqs) {
  return $(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], jqs.map(function (jq) { return Array.from(jq); })));
}
```