# How to pass two variables with selectors to $()

Tags: jquery

There is this code:

```
$(".field--name-field-upload-artwork details table, .field--name-field-upload-artwork .js-form-type-managed-file").wrapAll('<div class="upload-file-wrapper"></div>');
```

But I decided to add selectors to variables:

```
 let $uploadedFilesTable = $(".field--name-field-upload-artwork details table");
 let $dragAndDrop = $(".field--name-field-upload-artwork .js-form-type-managed-file");
```

Like this doesn't work:

```
$("${$uploadedFilesTable} + ',' + ${$dragAndDrop}").wrapAll('<div class="upload-file-wrapper"></div>');
```

And like this doesn't work:

```
$($uploadFilesTable + ',' + $dragAndDrop).wrapAll('<div class="upload-file-wrapper"></div>');
```

Comment: perhaps `[$uploadedFilesTable, $dragAndDrop].forEach($elem => $elem.wrap('<div class="upload-file-wrapper"></div>')`

Comment: It doesn't work because they're `jQuery` objects, not strings. You can `.add()` them: [Merging jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881716/merging-jquery-objects)

Comment: "But I decided to add selectors to variables" - If that was you intention, you didn't. Perhaps you meant `let uploadedFilesTable = ".field--name-field-upload-artwork details table";`?

Comment: let uploadedFilesTable = '.field--name-field-upload-artwork details table',
 dragAndDrop = 'field--name-field-upload-artwork .js-form-type-managed-file';

 $(uploadedFilesTable + ', ' + dragAndDrop).wrapAll('<div class="upload-file-wrapper"></div>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working Example how to use multiple variables in a selector. Check the below-working code snippet.

Hope this will solve your query.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   let $uploadedFilesTable = $(".field--name-field-upload-artwork .details");
   let $dragAndDrop = $(".field--name-field-upload-artwork .js-form-type-managed-file");
   $($dragAndDrop).add($uploadedFilesTable).wrapAll('<div class="upload-file-wrapper">file wrapper</div>')
 })
```

```css
.field--name-field-upload-artwork{
  background:#eaeaea;
  padding:10px;
}

.field--name-field-upload-artwork .details{
  background:blue;
  padding:10px;
}
.field--name-field-upload-artwork .js-form-type-managed-file{
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
}
.field--name-field-upload-artwork .upload-file-wrapper{
  background:yellow;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field--name-field-upload-artwork">
main container
  <div class="details">
    Details
  </div>
  <div class="js-form-type-managed-file">
  js-form-type-managed-file
  </div>
</div>
```