# Repeating functions

Tags: jquery

i seem to repeat alot of functions when coding something simple, is there a better way of doing this?

```
  $('#bt1').click(function() {
      $('#txt1').show();
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(site_images/08/btn_over.png)");  
}); 

  $('#bt2').click(function() {
      $('#txt2').show();
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(site_images/08/btn_over.png)");  
}); 

  $('#bt3').click(function() {
      $('#txt3').show();
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(site_images/08/btn_over.png)");  
}); 

  $('#bt4').click(function() {
      $('#txt4').show();
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(site_images/08/btn_over.png)");  
});
```

so that i'm not repeating code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give your buttons a `class`, such as `btn`, and then you can do something like:-

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#' + this.id.replace('bt', 'txt')).show();
  $(this).css("background-image", "url(site_images/08/btn_over.png)"); 
});
```

Comment: if I cought it right, this doesn't cover different texts which user want to display ... #txt1 .. #txt[n]

Comment: @LukasGreso It does. It takes the ID of the button that was clicked on (e.g. `bt1`) then replaces the `bt` part with `txt` to get the ID of the associated text to show; it's the first line of the event handler function.

Comment: YES YES, I see ... sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[id^='bt']").click(function() {
      var number = $(this).prop('id').slice(-1);
      $('#txt' + number).show();
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(site_images/08/btn_over.png)");  
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  Good to see a few different methods

Comment: @pouki06 You can easily use a regex to get the last number :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
$('#bt1,#bt2,#bt3,#bt4').click(function () {
    var number = this.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    $('#txt'+number).show();
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(site_images/08/btn_over.png)");
});
```

**note: better if you can add a class for all the items need to click. and then selecter will be changed to class name. rest of the code is same**

Comment: That doesn't extend nicely if they add new elements, and would still require them to list them all out individually.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, Hope you can see the note as well

Comment: I can, but it wasn't there when I wrote my comment. If you're aware that's the better solution why exactly would you suggest a different one?

Comment: Code sample is working without any changes to dom. but if he can change the dom he can go for the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#bt1, #bt2, #bt3, #bt4').click(function () {
    var number = this.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    $('#txt'+number).show();
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(site_images/08/btn_over.png)");
});
```

You can also .`add()` selectors: [How to combine two jQuery results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results)