# Hovering selectors, at least A or B

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I am looking for a jQuery selector that has an 'either' selection. The thing is, I have a dropdown menu and want them to leave on 2 options.

**Either when they leave the button or when they leave the menu that popped out.**

When I use `jQuery(".button, ul.menu").mouseleave` it will dissapear when I leave the button.

I want it to be different; at least **1** of the selectors **HAS to be hovered** to have the menu out.

How would I be able to do this?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".button").mouseover(function(){
    jQuery("ul.menu").stop().delay(600).fadeIn("fast");
  });
  jQuery("ul.menu, .button").mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery("ul.menu").stop().fadeOut("fast");
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you show us some code?

Comment: Can't this be used? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results

Comment: @r3c , I already tried .add but it sees them individually. I want them to literally be 'either'. Right now it looks as 'When .BUTTON OR ul.menu mouseleave it will dissapear'

Comment: `html` contents will be good too

Comment: @u_mulder can't I'm using forum software, it will be useless ;)

Comment: Produce some example on fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your HTML markup, but you wrap the two elements in a container like and handle the `mouseleave` on it, it will be fired she you leave the container; like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".button").mouseover(function(){
        jQuery("ul.menu").stop().delay(600).fadeIn("fast");
    });
    jQuery(".container").mouseleave(function(){
        jQuery("ul.menu").stop().fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```