# How to combine results of jQuery find() and filter()?

Tags: jquery, filter, find

Say I composed a DOM snippet:

```
var dom = $("
    <div id='root' class='abc'>
       <div id='child1' class='xxx'>no-match</div>
       <div id='child2' class='abc'>match!</div>
       <div id='child3' class='xxx'>no-match</div>
    </div>
");
```

and I want to retrieve all elements with '.abc' (i.e. #root and #child2)

dom.find('.abc') will return all matching child elements (ie. just #child2)
dom.filter('.abc') will return all matching root elements (ie. just #root)

How can I either:
- Make one call that finds both #root and #child2, or
- Combine the results of find() and filter()

I've seen other posts on "combining" results eg:
[How to combine two jQuery results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results)
but that's not really "combining" but rather "appending more results to a pre-existing result"

What I really want to do is something akin to `$.extend()`:

```
var one = dom.find('.abc');
var two = dom.filter('.abc');
var three = combine(one, two);
// or one.somefcn(two); // One is augmented
// or three = one.somefcn(two); //
```

Any info/ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I don't see why [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add) won't meet your needs.

Comment: I think I'm missing something - can you simplify your expected output and from what input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `add()` to combine selectors:

```
var $all = dom.find('.abc').add(dom.filter('.abc'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add) to combine selectors.

> Add elements to the set of matched elements.

```
var added = dom.find('.abc').add(dom.filter('.abc'));
```