# Intersect two jQuery selections

Tags: jquery

jQuery has the [ability to **union** the results of two selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results), using [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

var foosAndBars = $(".foo").add(".bar"); //select all elements classes .foo or .bar

But i need to perform an **intersection** of two sets:

```
var allTRs = $("#lvTransactions").find("[data-language]").closest("tr")
var trMatchingLanguage= allTRs.find("[data-language]").filter("[data-language='pascal'],[data-language='C#'],[data-langauge='Ook']").closest("tr");
var trMatchingTag = allTRs.find("data-tag").filter("[data-tag='wpf'").closest("tr");
```

I need the `TR` elements common in both sets, as those are the ones to be shown:

```
allTRs.hide();    
trMatchingLanguage.intersect(trMatchingTag ).show();
```

**Edit**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXdM7/6/):

Show all rows that have:

- **data-language**: `pascal` or `C#`
- **data-tag**: `wpf`

with the following sample table:

```
<div id="lvTransactions">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Question</th><th>Lanaguage</th><th>Tag</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>How to</td>
            <td data-language="C">C</td>
            <td data-tag="wpf">Windows Presentation Foundation</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Why does</td>
            <td data-language="pascal">Pascal</td>
            <td data-tag="dwm">Windows Presentation Foundation</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Why can't</td>
            <td data-language="pascal">Pascal</td>
            <td data-tag="wpf">Desktop Window Manager</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Does it</td>
            <td data-language="C#">C#</td>
            <td data-tag="wpf">Desktop Window Manager</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Where is</td>
            <td data-language="Java">Java</td>
            <td data-tag="wpf">Windows Presentation Foundation</td>
        </tr>            
    </table>
</div>
```

And right now i have the (faulty) code (that shows the union, rather than the intersection):

```
//Only show rows that are both C#/Pascal and WPF

var allTRs = $("#lvTransactions").find("[data-language]").closest("tr")

var theLanguageTRs = allTRs.find("[data-language]").filter("[data-language='pascal'],[data-language='C#'],[data-langauge='ook']").closest("tr");
var theTagTRs = allTRs.find("[data-tag]").filter("[data-tag='wpf']").closest("tr");
```

Comment: Seeing the HTML would be helpful.

Comment: [`_.intersection`](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) is your friend ^^

Comment: mwell, you can multiple criteria in your selector like `$(".foo.bar")`. Elements that have both classes foo and bar

Comment: @moonwave99: That's underscore, not jQuery...

Comment: @TCHdvlp the problems is that the elements aren't together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something as simple as:

```
$(array1).filter(array2);
```

Reference: [`$.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: That works! It took me about [two hours to get some jsFiddle that compiles](http://jsfiddle.net/eXdM7/15/). Then i could validate your theory.