# How to group jquery objects to apply css together?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a function that accepts multiple jQuery objects:

```
workWithThreeObjs($('.content'),
                  $('h1'),
                  $('input[type=button]'));
```

I define my function like this:

```
function workWithThreeObjs(p, h1, buttons) {
    ...
}
```

Inside this function, I want to apply border to all of them like this

```
$(p, h1, buttons).css(...);
```

How do I do that? Right now it only applies to `p`.

My function code does not control what is passed into it, so I cannot change the selectors used to create the arguments. I must operate only on the jQuery objects provided.

Comment: Google has only shown me duplicates which are different so not a duplicates. They talk about grouping selectors not objects.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer It **is** a duplicate, I've seen it many times, but "add" is such a common term it's hard to find on SO...

Comment: i agree with you @DenysSéguret . i have seen it many times too.

Comment: @DavidThomas http://jsfiddle.net/ddxhw21b/1/see for yourself

Comment: I stand corrected; I'm a little surprised by that (though I'm not sure why).

Comment: Or, possibly an even better option: [How to combine two jQuery results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results)

Comment: @apsillers agree with the second option - have voted to close the first as a duplicate of the second

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Assuming that you want to use variables*

*Use* [`$.fn.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

```
var p = $('.content'),
    h1 = $('h1'),
    buttons = $('input[type=button]');

p.add(h1).add(buttons).css({})
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/6gyjeqpa/)</kbd>

Comment: not sure why the discussion is continuing elsewhere, this is the answer. At least until someone finds the right duplicate to mark it with

Answer (score 2):

```
var p = $('.content'),
        h1 = $('h1'),
        buttons = $('input[type=button]');

function workAnyNumberofObjects() {
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    arguments[i].css('border', '1px solid blue')
  }
}

workAnyNumberofObjects(p,h1,buttons);
```

You should be able to use any number of selectors here

Comment: yes but i already have selectors deep in code, and they are specific based on some alogrithim. This example was meant to show what i wanted to do not how my code is.

Comment: Then give a better example of what you're doing to show your problem.