# How to addClass or set multiple CSS properties to multiple elements which has variables?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I addClass or add css properties to multiple elements(id's) which has variables assigned to them. The code works if I use directly `$('#cc, #dd').addClass('blue')` but doesn't work if it has variables assigned to id's like `$(cc, dd).addClass('blue')`. Please check the below code, the commented line works but not if it has variables.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cc = $("#cc"),
        dd = $("#dd");
    $("button").click(function() {
        // $("#cc, #dd").addClass("blue");
        $(cc, dd).addClass("blue");
        $(cc, dd).css({
            "color": "#2196f3",
            "font-size": "30px"
        });
        $("h1, h2, p").addClass("blue");
    });
});
```

```css
.blue {
  color: #2196f3;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<div id="cc">hello 1</div>
<div id="dd">hello 2</div>

<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Add classes to elements</button>
```

Comment: try cc.addClass('blue');

Comment: You can add a common class for cc and dd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two jQuery results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add the dd element to the cc collection, right now you are trying to find a cc element inside the dd element see [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)

```js
var cc = $("#cc"),
    dd = $("#dd");
$(cc).add(dd).addClass("blue");
```

```css
.blue {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cc"></button>
<button id="dd"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cc = $("#cc"),
      dd = $("#dd");
  $("button").click(function() {
      // $("#cc, #dd").addClass("blue");
      dd.addClass("blue");
      cc.addClass("blue");
      $(cc, dd).css({
          "color": "#2196f3",
          "font-size": "30px"
      });
      //$("h1, h2, p").addClass("blue");
  });
});
```

```css
.blue {
    color: #2196f3;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="cc">hello 1</div>
<div id="dd">hello 2</div>

<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Add classes to elements</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could  use an array and join:

```
var arrSelectors = ["#cc", "#dd", ".someOtherSelector"];

$(arrSelectors.join).addClass("blue");
```

Comment: they are not strings they are jquery objects so this should not work

Comment: @madalinivascu correct, not enough coffee in the system... revising my answer to an alternate approach.