# Combine jQuery objects from multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a function that returns a jQuery object of all of the elements of a given selector across paged content.

```
const getPagedContent = async (base, selector) => {
    let elements = [];
    let lastPage = 1;
    let page = 0;
    while (lastPage > page) {
        page++;
        let response = await got(`${base}/page/${page}`);
        let html = new jsdom.JSDOM(response.body);

        elements.push($(html).find(selector));

        lastPage = getLastPage(html);
    }
    return elements;
}
```

However, this does return a jQuery object with all the elements but (obviously) an array with multiple jQuery objects. How can I add the results from each page so I can return one jQuery object with all the elements?

*Edit:*
Attempting to use `.add` returns a jQuery object with a length of 0. I am not sure how to adopt add for multiple doms.

```
const getPagedContent = async (base, selector) => {
    let elements = $();
    let lastPage = 1;
    let page = 0;
    while (lastPage > page) {
        page++;
        let response = await got(`${base}/page/${page}`);
        let html = new jsdom.JSDOM(response.body);

        elements.add($(html).find(selector));

        lastPage = getLastPage(html);
    }
    console.dir(elements);
    console.log('Items length:', elements.length);
    return elements;
}
```

```
jQuery {}
Items length: 0
```

Comment: What's a "*jQuery object*"? Do you mean a jQuery element? Or maybe a JavaScript object containing jQuery elements? If the second, what should the keys be?

Comment: Is what is returned by `.find` not an object of jQuery elements? I am looking to merge the elements from multiple pages to look as if the results from `.find` was ran on all pages.

Comment: I see what you mean now, does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results/323969?

Comment: I have not had success using add. I have edited the question above to show what I have tried.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It would make debugging this issue so much easier.

Comment: If I understand the questionar right, he wants to use a jquery object as container for another jquery objects insteand of an array. In my eyes not possible, because jquery object is not compatible for this usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is indeed jQuery's [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/). The only problem with your current code is coming from the fact the `.add()` method does ***not*** mutate the jQuery object that called it, instead, it returns a new jQuery object with the combined contents of the caller and the added element.

The newly generated object needs to be assigned to caller as such:

```js
let elements = $();
elements = elements.add($('some selector'));
```

The code snippet below illustrates a working example of this approach.

```js
let elements = $();

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    elements = elements.add($(`.outer${i}`).find('.inner'));
}

console.log(elements.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer0">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer1">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```