# get parent or previous element based on child or sibling class

Tags: jquery

Imagine I have three different types of product HTML and I want to select the `product-block` element for only those that have a child or sibling with an input element that has a class `mySelector`.

- Type A has the element with 'mySelector' within.
- Type B doesn't have an element 'mySelector' within or below it, so we don't want to select it.
- Type C has the element 'mySelector' right after it.

The goal is to select the product block `<div>` of types A and C, which have a child or sibling with `mySelector`.

**Product block type A**

```
<div class="A B C">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <input type="hidden" class="mySelector">
</div>
```

**Product block type B**

```
<div class="MM NN OO">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

**Product block type C**

```
<div class="X Y Z">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" class="mySelector">
```

I imagine a filter could work, but I only can select one type of product-block with a filter like this:

```
jQuery('.mySelector')
    .filter(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).prev().hasClass('Z')) {
           return jQuery(this).prev();
        }
    })
```

Another approach is using `jQuery('.mySelector').parent()`. But then I would not be able to select type C where `mySelector` is a sibling.

Comment: Use both (get all the parent ones and get all the prev ones) then combine with `.add()` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/323969/2181514 (not intended as a duplicate)

Comment: I just came across the same one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as @freedomn-m suggested.

```
let elmsa = jQuery('.mySelector').parent()
               .filter(function () {
                  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('A')) {
                   return this;
                  }
               });

let elmsb = jQuery('.mySelector').prev()
                .filter(function () {
                   if (jQuery(this).hasClass('X')) {
                       return this;
                   }
                });

let elms = jQuery.merge(elmsa, elmsb);
```